# has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items. Parameter name: value

Tags: asp.net

I have created a DetailsView in asp.net and in that view I am using Template fields. In my form I am asking for the gender of the user. I would like to us a simple dropdown list to accomplish this but I am getting the following error whenever I hit the 'Edit' link. - "'ddlEditGender' has a `SelectedValue` which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items.
Parameter name: value."

Before I hit the edit button I can see that this is displayed in the DetailsView:

`entity_id  4
Full Name   LastName2
First Name  Test2
Last Name   Last2
Gender      Male
Note        This is another test user account`

Below is the mark up for my Template:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Gender" SortExpression="gender">
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlEditGender" runat="server" Width="140px" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("gender", "{0}") %>' AppendDataBoundItems="True" >
        <asp:ListItem Value="Male"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Female"></asp:ListItem> </asp:DropDownList>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <InsertItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("gender") %>'></asp:TextBox>
    </InsertItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("gender") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: isn't clear what the error says ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like after the *Edit* link is clicked the property for **`gender`** no longer exists.Please make sure that when you re-bind your `DetailsView` with data after clicking *Edit* that you're including the **`gender`** property.Have a look at the working example below, I hope it helps you find your problem:

**.ASPX:**

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" Height="50px" Width="125px" AutoGenerateEditButton="True" AutoGenerateRows="False" OnModeChanging="DetailsView1_ModeChanging">
    <Fields>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="First Name">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblFirst" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("FirstName") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirst" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("FirstName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Gender">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblFirst" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Gender") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlEditGender" runat="server" Width="140px" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("gender", "{0}") %>' AppendDataBoundItems="True">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Male"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Female"></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Fields>
</asp:DetailsView>
```

**Code behind:**

```
public class Customer
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
}

public partial class DetailsViewExample : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!Page.IsPostBack)
            BindDetails();
    }

    private void BindDetails()
    {
        DetailsView1.DataSource = new List<Customer> { new Customer { FirstName = "Customer 1", Gender = "Male" } };
        DetailsView1.DataBind();
    }

    protected void DetailsView1_ModeChanging(object sender, DetailsViewModeEventArgs e)
    {
        DetailsView1.ChangeMode(DetailsViewMode.Edit);
        BindDetails();
    }
}
```